# How to perform string Diffs in Java?

Tags: java, diff

I need to perform Diffs between Java strings. I would like to be able to rebuild a string using the original string and diff versions. Has anyone done this in Java? What library do you use?

```
String a1; // This can be a long text
String a2; // ej. above text with spelling corrections
String a3; // ej. above text with spelling corrections and an additional sentence

Diff diff = new Diff();
String differences_a1_a2 = Diff.getDifferences(a,changed_a);
String differences_a2_a3 = Diff.getDifferences(a,changed_a);    
String[] diffs = new String[]{a,differences_a1_a2,differences_a2_a3};
String new_a3 = Diff.build(diffs);
a3.equals(new_a3); // this is true
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479654/java-library-for-free-text-diff

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This library seems to do the trick: [google-diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch). It can create a patch string from differences and allow to reapply the patch.

**edit**: Another solution might be to https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/

Comment: Those are different libs, FWIW

Comment: Maven repository for the google-diff-match-patch is [there](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/Home).

Comment: The actively maintained fork of java-diff-utils seems to be https://github.com/bkromhout/java-diff-utils

Comment: `google-diff-match-patch` on github: https://github.com/GerHobbelt/google-diff-match-patch

Comment: The maintained fork seems to be now https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils

Answer (score 27):

Apache Commons has String diff

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

```
StringUtils.difference("foobar", "foo");
```

Comment: It returns the remainder of the second String, starting from where it's different from the first. Which is not efficient enough for me since i would be working with big texts. See: 
StringUtils.difference("ab", "abxyz") -> "xyz"
StringUtils.difference("ab", "xyzab") -> "xyzab";

Comment: Also beware this gotcha:
`StringUtils.difference("abc", "") = ""`
`StringUtils.difference("abc", "abc") = ""`

Answer (score 4):

The [java diff utills](https://github.com/dnaumenko/java-diff-utils) library might be useful.

Comment: The repo https://github.com/bkromhout/java-diff-utils/ forked indirectly from the original GitHub repository and is better maintained. Maybe you can join forces there?

Answer (score 3):

As Torsten Says you can use

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

```
System.err.println(StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance("foobar", "bar"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but getLevenshteinDistance just returns an integer. That's not enough to rebuild the strings.

Comment: @hstoerr you are correct I must of missed this part in the original question. Long time ago now :)

Comment: That method is also deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with differences between big amounts of data and have the differences efficiently compressed, you could try a Java implementation of xdelta, which in turn implements RFC 3284 (VCDIFF) for binary diffs (should work with strings too).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and extract the edit logs from the matrix the algorithm builds up. The Wikipedia article links to a couple of implementations, I'm sure there's a Java implementation among in.

Levenshtein is a special case of the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm, you might also want to have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Text now has [StringsComparator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/diff/StringsComparator.html):

```
StringsComparator c = new StringsComparator(s1, s2);
c.getScript().visit(new CommandVisitor<Character>() {

    @Override
    public void visitKeepCommand(Character object) {
        System.out.println("k: " + object);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInsertCommand(Character object) {
        System.out.println("i: " + object);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitDeleteCommand(Character object) {
        System.out.println("d: " + object);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to discover, (for a regression test, where I didn't need diffing support in production) that `assertj` provides built-in access for `java-diff-utils`.  See its DiffUtils, InputStream, or Diff classes, for example.

Answer (score -7):

```
public class Stringdiff {
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println(strcheck("sum","sumsum"));
}
public static String strcheck(String str1,String str2){
    if(Math.abs((str1.length()-str2.length()))==-1){
        return "Invalid";
    }
    int num=diffcheck1(str1, str2);
    if(num==-1){
        return "Empty";
    }
    if(str1.length()>str2.length()){
        return str1.substring(num);
    }
    else{
        return str2.substring(num);
    }

}

public static int diffcheck1(String str1,String str2)
{
    int i;
    String str;
    String strn;
    if(str1.length()>str2.length()){
        str=str1;
        strn=str2;
    }
    else{
        str=str2;
        strn=str1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<str.length() && i<strn.length();i++){
            if(str1.charAt(i)!=str2.charAt(i)){
                return i;
            }
    }
        if(i<str1.length()||i<str2.length()){
            return i;
        }

    return -1;

   }
   }
```

Comment: Untested plain text code like this almost never makes sense. Create a project on a FLOSS code hosting page and provide the code + tests there.