# Text difference algorithm

Tags: c#, python, diff

I need an algorithm that can compare two text files and highlight their difference and  ( even better!) can compute their difference in a meaningful way (like two similar files should have a similarity score higher than two dissimilar files, with the word "similar" defined in the normal terms). It sounds easy to implement, but it's not.

The implementation can be in c# or python.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking for textual similarity or semantic similarity?

Comment: Textual similarity. I supposed that semantic similarity still has a long way to go :)

Comment: It's not that difficult. A simple bag-of-words model goes a long way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Python, there is [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), as also others have suggested.

`difflib` offers the [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) class, which can be used to give you a similarity ratio. Example function:

```
def text_compare(text1, text2, isjunk=None):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk, text1, text2).ratio()
```

Answer (score 30):

I can recommend to take a look at Neil Fraser's code and articles:

[google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

> Currently available in Java,
>   JavaScript, C++ and Python. Regardless
>   of language, each library features the
>   same API and the same functionality.
>   All versions also have comprehensive
>   test harnesses.

[Neil Fraser: Diff Strategies](http://neil.fraser.name/writing/diff/) - for theory and implementation notes

Answer (score 24):

Look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-difflib.html). (Python)

That will calculate the diffs in various formats. You could then use the size of the context diff as a measure of how different two documents are?

Answer (score 12):

My current understanding is that the best solution to the Shortest Edit Script (SES) problem is Myers "middle-snake" method with the Hirschberg linear space refinement.

The Myers algorithm is described in:

> E. Myers, ``An O(ND) Difference
>   Algorithm and Its Variations,''
>   Algorithmica 1, 2 (1986), 251-266.

The GNU diff utility uses the Myers algorithm.

The "similarity score" you speak of is called the "edit distance" in the literature which is the number of inserts or deletes necessary to transform one sequence into the other.

Note that a number of people have cited the Levenshtein distance algorithm but that is, albeit easy to implement, not the optimal solution as it is inefficient (requires the use of a possibly huge n*m matrix) and does not provide the "edit script" which is the sequence of edits that could be used to transform one sequence into the other and vice versa.

For a good Myers / Hirschberg implementation look at:

http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/dl/src/diff.c

The particular library that it is contained within is no longer maintained but to my knowledge the diff.c module itself is still correct.

Mike

Answer (score 10):

[Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/) contains an alternative difference algorithm, called [patience diff](http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/37690.html) (there's more info in the comments on that page) which is claimed to be better than the traditional diff algorithm. The file 'patiencediff.py' in the bazaar distribution is a simple command line front end.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a finer granularity than lines, you can use Levenshtein distance. Levenshtein distance is a straight-forward measure on how to similar two texts are.
You can also use it to extract the edit logs and can a very fine-grained diff, similar to that on the edit history pages of SO.
Be warned though that Levenshtein distance can be quite CPU- and memory-intensive to calculate, so using difflib,as Douglas Leder suggested, is most likely going to be faster.

Cf. also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java#132547).

Comment: I think you need to put in a link to that Cf. at the end. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of distance metrics, as paradoja mentioned there is the Levenshtein distance, but there is also [NYSIIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_State_Identification_and_Intelligence_System) and [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).  In terms of Python implementations, I have used [py-editdist](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-editdist/) and [ADVAS](http://advas.sourceforge.net/) before.  Both are nice in the sense that you get a single number back as a score.  Check out ADVAS first, it implements a bunch of algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, use difflib. Once you have the diffed output, you may find the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of the different strings as to give a "value" of how different they are.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [solution to the Longest Common Subsequence (LCS) problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_for_the_dynamic_programming_solution). See also the discussion about possible ways to optimize this solution.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've employed for a different functionality, to calculate how much data was new in a modified file, could perhaps work for you as well.

I have a diff/patch implementation C# that allows me to take two files, presumably old and new version of the same file, and calculate the "difference", but not in the usual sense of the word. Basically I calculate a set of operations that I can perform on the old version to update it to have the same contents as the new version.

To use this for the functionality initially described, to see how much data was new, I simple ran through the operations, and for every operation that copied from the old file verbatim, that had a 0-factor, and every operation that inserted new text (distributed as part of the patch, since it didn't occur in the old file) had a 1-factor. All characters was given this factory, which gave me basically a long list of 0's and 1's.

All I then had to do was to tally up the 0's and 1's. In your case, with my implementation, a low number of 1's compared to 0's would mean the files are very similar.

This implementation would also handle cases where the modified file had inserted copies from the old file out of order, or even duplicates (ie. you copy a part from the start of the file and paste it near the bottom), since they would both be copies of the same original part from the old file.

I experimented with weighing copies, so that the first copy counted as 0, and subsequent copies of the same characters had progressively higher factors, in order to give a copy/paste operation some "new-factor", but I never finished it as the project was scrapped.

If you're interested, my diff/patch code is available from my Subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Fuzzy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy) module. It has fast (written in C) based algorithms for soundex, NYSIIS and double-metaphone.

A good introduction can be found at: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1848528