# percentage difference between two text files

Tags: python, linux, algorithm, language-agnostic

I know that I can use cmp, diff, etc to compare two files, but what I am looking for is a utility that gives me percentage difference between two files.

if there is no such utility, any algorithm would do fine too. I have read about fuzzy programming, but I have not quite understand it.

Comment: How do you define "percentage difference"?  How do you account for missing, extra and swapped characters/words/lines?

Comment: there will not be any swapped characters or word or lines in the files. the two files are log files, one log file is all well log file, which means system is running perfect. in every hour new log is written. so I want compare newly written log to standard log. if the new log is different than the standard log, then mail to level {X} support engineer. is it clear now?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use difflib.SequenceMatcher [ratio](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) method

From the documentation:

> Return a measure of the
>   sequences’ similarity as a float in
>   the range [0, 1].

For example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
text1 = open(file1).read()
text2 = open(file2).read()
m = SequenceMatcher(None, text1, text2)
m.ratio()
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I do find that it can be pretty slow to run. If you look in the documentation can use m.quick_ratio() or m.real_quick_ratio() as a much cheaper option but has less accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Linux has a utility called dwdiff that can give percentage differences by using the "-s" flag

http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/diff_tools.shtml

Answer (score 1):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) has very nice file difference statistics export to csv. Differences at line level are reported so it's nice to compare source code files.