# What is the algorithm of linux diff -y?

Tags: algorithm, diff

The ever-helpful Wikipedia claims that diff implements Longest Common Subsequence.

This cannot be so. Diff, at least in -y mode, has three types of report: add, remove, and substitute. LCS does not have any concept of 'substitute'.

What is the algorithm of diff? I have reason to not believe that it is Levenshtein distance, but I might have misanalyzed this.

Comment: Can't an insertion and a deletion next to each other be considered a substitution?

Comment: The corresponding source code uses only add and remove. Looks like longest common subsequence at first glance...
(See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/analyze.c?id=fecd0079fe6e15b0f53bf953721d838d9099bf05)

Comment: @mre, diff -y produces 'common' lines indicated by vertical bars.

Comment: I see. My assumption was wrong but at least I learned something along the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm/478615#478615) (by [ioplex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8134/ioplex)) says that GNU diff implements "O(ND) diff algorithm" by Eugene Myers.