# Print only one in a double loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I´m making a searching tool with Python for a csv file. In the last lines of code I make a double loop:

```
for letterText in Text:
    for letterBook in i:
        if letterText == letterBook:
            count = count + 1
        if count >= countLetter/2:
            print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
            break
```

But the problem is that I want to print `(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())`  only once per`i` . I can´t figure out what I´m doing wrong. Thank you for your help. Here is the full code.

```
import csv
Text = input("Book...")
data = open(r"C:\Users\file.csv")
dataReader = csv.reader(data, delimiter = ";")
count = 0
countLetter = 0
bookList= dict()
letterList= list()

for letterText in Text:
    letterList.append(letterText)
    countLetter = countLetter + 1

for row in dataReader:
    bookList[row[0]]= row[1]

for (i) in bookList:
    for letterBook in i:
        LetterBookList = list(letterBook)
    count = 0
    #exact book name typed
    if Text == i:
        print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
    for letterText in Text:
        for letterBook in i:
            if letterText == letterBook:
                count = count + 1
            if count >= countLetter/2:
                print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
                break
```

Comment: How does the `input("Book...")` look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. This would be easier to answer if you provided a [mre]. At the moment your example isn't reproducible since it's missing the user input, CSV, output, and desired output. Though it might be clearer if you get rid of the input and CSV and just put them statically in the code.

Comment: Are u trying to see if any typed text matches a part of the book title in any way. as in inputting "is" will give us all the book titles containing "is" ?

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp I'm trying to get printed all the book that have at least half or their words equal to the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that `break` works for inner loop only (`for letterBook in i:`). You need to change your code to also break from the outer loop (`for letterText in Text:`) and put it into an `else` branch of `if Text == i:`. Your code seems to check for partial text match. For that I would recommend using some other techniques like builtin [difflib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551701/8014793)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many info, but you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to keep track of what you printed and check on it, here's a modified code

```
printed = set()
for letterText in Text:
    for letterBook in i:
        if letterText == letterBook:
            count = count + 1
        if count >= countLetter/2 and i not in set:
            print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
            printed.add(i)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you have two *for* loops and only one break statement.

Once `count >= countLetter/2` is true, `i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper()` is printed and then the break statement is called. The break statement breaks out of the `for letterBook in i` loop but it does not break out of the `for letterText in Text` loop and therefore this loop goes onto its next iteration and so on.

I often use flag variables to break out of such loops. A flag variable like a boolean variable could be false initially but will store true once `count >= countLetter/2` is true and if the flag variable is true, another break statement is executed in the `for letterText in Text` loop.

Check out the code below:

```
import csv
Text = input("Book...")
data = open(r"C:\Users\file.csv")
dataReader = csv.reader(data, delimiter = ";")
count = 0
countLetter = 0
bookList= dict()
letterList= list()

for letterText in Text:
    letterList.append(letterText)
    countLetter = countLetter + 1

for row in dataReader:
    bookList[row[0]]= row[1]

for (i) in bookList:
    for letterBook in i:
        LetterBookList = list(letterBook)
    count = 0
    #exact book name typed
    halfThresholdReached = False
    if Text == i:
        print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
        continue

    for letterText in Text:
        for letterBook in i:
            if letterText == letterBook:
                count = count + 1
            if count >= countLetter/2:
                print(i.upper(),":",bookList[i].upper())
                halfThresholdReached = True
                break
        if halfThresholdReached:
            break
```

EDIT: There is another piece that I forgot to look at. You are also checking if `if Text == i` in the `for (i) in bookList` loop and if this is true, then you must continue on to the next iteration of the same loop and not check the rest of the *Text*. So if it returns true, then add a `continue` statement to proceed to the next iteration.