# python search technology: word similarity

Tags: python, search, search-engine, similarity

I want to get a similarity percentage of two words, eg)

```
abcd versus zzabcdzz == 50% similarity
```

Don't need to be very accurate. Is there any way to do that? I am using python but feel free to recomment other languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text difference algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`python-Levenshtein`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) to calculate the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

> The Levenshtein Python C extension module contains functions for fast computation of
>
> - Levenshtein (edit) distance, and edit operations
> - string similarity
> - approximate median strings, and generally string averaging
> - string sequence and set similarity

You can get a rough idea of similarity by calculating the edit distance between the two strings divided by the length of the longest string. In your example the edit distance is 4, and the maximum possible edit distance is 8, so the similarity is 50%.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the python inbuilt module [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

Here's an example from that page

```
>>> s = SequenceMatcher(None, "abcd", "bcde")
>>> s.ratio()
0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

some similarity metrics from nltk library:

http://www.opendocs.net/nltk/0.9.5/api/nltk.wordnet.similarity-module.html

Answer (score 0):

Copying from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm/146957#146957) answer:

In Python, there is [difflib](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-difflib.html).

`difflib` offers the [SequenceMatcher](http://docs.python.org/lib/sequence-matcher.html) class, which can be used to give you a similarity ratio. Example function:

```
def text_compare(text1, text2, isjunk=None):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk, text1, text2).ratio()
```