# comparison of two strings and returning the one most similar

Tags: python, comparison

I have to write a function that takes a string as  argument and compair this string to two other strings and return the string most similar and the number of differences.

```
def func("LUMB"):
    lst=["JIBM", "NUNE", "NUMB"]
should return:
("NUMB",1)
```

I have tried:

```
def f(word):
    lst=["JIBM", "NUNE", "NUMB"]
    for i in lst:
        d=k(word, lst)
        return differences
        for n in d:
            print min(sum(n))
```

where:

```
def k(word1, word2):
    L=[]
    for w in range(len(word1)):
        if word1[w] != word2[w]:
            L.append(1)
        else:
            L.append(0)
    return L
```

so that i get a list of eg, [1,0,0,0] if word1="NUMB" and word2="LUMB"

Comment: Have you seen [Text difference algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm) and [Good Python modules for fuzzy string comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Comment: A number of answers would be available on this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison

Comment: On the site there is a similar post. You would get some more valuable answers over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions by deleting the code.

Comment: @talonmies Has the code been restored after being deleted?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like Shawn Chin has provided the best solution, but if you're prevented from using non-builtin modules, it seems like [`get_close_matches`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) from `difflib` might help:

```
import difflib
difflib.get_close_matches("LUMB", ["JIBM", "NUNE", "NUMB"], 1)
```

The number of differences can be gotten using the [`get_opcodes`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes) method of [`SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) and working with its return value.

Comment: While this does not return the edit distance, I like that it uses only the standard library. +1

Answer (score 6):

Using [pylevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/) to calculate [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
>>> from Levenshtein import distance
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = ["JIBM", "NUNE", "NUMB"]
>>> min([(x, distance("LUMB", x)) for x in lst], key=itemgetter(1))
('NUMB', 1)
```

Or, as a function:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
from operator import itemgetter
def closest(word, lst):
    return min([(x, distance(word, x)) for x in lst], key=itemgetter(1))

print closest("NUMB", ["JIBM", "NUNE", "NUMB"])
```

---

p.s. If you want to avoid additional dependencies, you could always implement your own function for calculating the distance. For example, several version are proposed in [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python) each with their own pros and cons.

However, if performance is a concern, do consider sticking to the custom built modules. Apart from [pylevenshtein](http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/), there's also [python-levenshtein](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein) and [`nltk.metrics.distance`](http://nltk.github.com/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.distance) (if you happen to already use [NLTK](http://nltk.github.com)).