# GIT: how does git know the changes of a text file?

Tags: git, version-control

for example, by `git diff file`, we can know that we deleted 3 lines, inserted 1 line and modified 3 lines. but how can git achieve it ? Does it track the process of my editting? Does vim leave some special files for git to achiebe it?

I mean, if I modified one line, I can also say that I delete one line and insert one line. How does git know that I modified this line rather than doing deletion and insertion?

Comment: You should review a good Git tutorial to get a thorough answer to your questions.  For your second question, the answer is that sometimes Git sees it as a deletion followed by insertion, and other times it sees it as a modification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it track the process of my editing?

No.

It checks for the modifications by comparing the cached version (stored in the .git folder) and the current version.

> Does vim leave some special files for git to achieve it?

No

> *...* How does git know that I modified this line rather than doing deletion and insertion?

In short, it checks for the similarities as well as the differences in two files by using an algorithm that answers the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). It's important to know that `diff` is not a command only present in `git` - it is also a [Linux/Unix command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

There are many algorithms that can be used to find the difference between two files, such as the [Hunt–McIlroy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93McIlroy_algorithm) and Myer's diff algorithm.

Rather than looking for a specific answer for `git diff`, I suggest you look into the two above algorithms instead.

See this question for more details: [Myers diff algorithm vs Hunt–McIlroy algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635889/myers-diff-algorithm-vs-hunt-mcilroy-algorithm)

Comment: yeah, I know about the  longest common subsequence problem, but it is about the character level. I mean, you can have a word **aaabbbccc** and modify it to be **xyzabcdef** , the LCS is **abc**  but LCS doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Astute observation -- there is more than just an algorithm being used. For instance, the line number is also being taken in consideration. So even if `abcdef` becomes `ghijkl`, because the line number matches, it will be considered as a modification rather than an insertion/deletion.

Comment: If you want, you can check git's diff source code here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c