# How does git generate diff in files?

Tags: git

What mechanism does git follow while `diff`ing files? How is git able to tell me the difference between the two files(two commits, etc)?
Does it follow any key-value pair mechanism where line number is the key and value is the hash and if the hash changes, the line is marked as the changed line?

Comment: `git` is free software, so you could study its source code...

Comment: Can you show an example of a diff that git has produced for binary files? As far as I know, once git detects that the files are binary in nature, it won't produce any diffs for them.

Comment: Or are you simply asking how git can tell that the files are different?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ok, i would like to know how does it show the difference in two files if not binary.

Comment: Please clean up your question, right now I'm not entirely sure what you're really asking about.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen check now

Comment: You can tell git how to convert the binary to text and diff that result.  This answer may help: https://superuser.com/questions/706042/how-can-i-diff-binary-files-in-git (look at the "bin" for a generic binary file)

Comment: I still don't understand your question, you keep saying binary files, and then you talk about "the line", I would still like to see an example of such a diff. You don't get diff from git if it thinks the file is binary, only if it thinks the file is text (non-binary).

Comment: In other words, the only answer that can be provided to your answer right now is "it doesn't, git does not diff binary files".

Comment: I had changed the context to files and not binary files, check the question.

Comment: The second question still mentions binary files.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister done

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/.  Git uses the Myers diffing strategy by default, but it can also use the patience algorithm: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/09/19/the-patience-diff-algorithm/  (and here's the creator of the algorithms description: https://bramcohen.livejournal.com/73318.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question asked about *binary* files, which in Git, means "files that Git has decided are not text".  For such files, unless you provide a special diff driver, Git does not attempt to generate a diff, it only says "these two files are the same" or "these two files are different".  (A diff driver is an external program: you can instruct Git to run this program instead, and this program can do whatever *it* wants to do with the pair of files, to generate a useable diff.)

Your updated question, at least as of this time, asks about diffing *text* files.  Git has built into it a modified version of [LibXDiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html).  [The main algorithm here is due to Eugene Myers](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf).  See also [Myers diff algorithm vs Hunt–McIlroy algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635889/1256452).  For a somewhat more user-friendly introduction to diff algorithms, see the last section of chapter 3 of [my stalled book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).  You are in fact onto something with the idea of line hashes: these diff algorithms compare *symbols*, and using a line-hash as the symbols in the diff matrix is how they find line-by-line diffs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it generates a checksum of the file and compare those, if they are different the file will be marked as modified, but it **will not** tell you the difference because simply it doesn't know it.