# git: Undo changes in a function

Tags: git

When we do a `git diff`, it very well shows us the diff alongwith the line numbers and the function in which the lines fall:

```
@@ -614,10 +636,10 @@ def write_my_name(name):
                         .
                         .
-                        len(name),
+                        len(getattr(resume, name)),
```

When I do a `git add` is it also storing these function references?

Also to consider, we have `git log -L<func_name>:file_name`, not sure how that works. My guess is reference to function is being stored?

If the answer to above questions is yes. Is it possible to undo changes in a particular function? I am unable to find a switch in `reset`.

Would like to consider both scenarios, changes not staged and changes staged for commit.

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Comment: My guess is that when you as for -L<func_name>, git is analyzing the file "on the fly". I'm sure that git does not parse the file as it is being saved into the objects DB.

Comment: Although I find this question interesting, I think it's off topic, because it's not about programming, even in the sense of solving a problem with a version control tool. OTOH, I'm pretty sure @eftshift0 is right. I remember reading something about how `git diff --function-context` worked that mentioned that it was calculated when the diff was calculated.

Comment: VTC because it's a question about how a particular (devops) program works internally, not a problem with using it. I don't think that's on-topic on Super User, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we do a `git diff`, it very well shows us the diff along with the line numbers and the function in which the lines fall ...

Yes, but it's all based on a trick. :-)

First, `git diff` finds an edit sequence (see links in my answer to [How does git generate diff in files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54112099/1256452)).  Then it uses the edit sequence to claim that this is what you did, even if that's not actually what you did—it's just a change that will *accomplish the same thing*, if applied to the same input.

Then, given that Git is presenting a change as affectling lines M-through-N, Git does a regular expression search through lines whose number is less than or equal to M (essentially, tests each line, starting at M, moving towards line 1).  [These regular expressions are built in to the Git source.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62/userdiff.c#L10-L176)  You can set your own, as documented (somewhat) in [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (search for "defining a custom hunk-header").  If the expression matches the line, the text is included after the `@@`.

> When I do a `git add` is it also storing these function references?

No: `git add` merely copies the work-tree version of the file into the index, replacing whatever version was in the index before.  Note, however, that `git add -p` runs [a Perl script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-add--interactive.perl).  That script does something very different; read it to see precisely what it does, and how it does it.

> Also to consider, we have `git log -L<func_name>:file_name`, not sure how that works.

That, too, uses the regular expression match trick to find functions within files.

> Is it possible to undo changes in a particular function? I am unable to find a switch in `reset`.

It currently is not.  To do that, you could modify the Perl script, because `git reset -p` *also* invokes this same perl script.  Unfortunately, the built-in regular expressions are not exported—so you could read the user's configuration to check for *custom* regular expressions, but otherwise you would have to re-code the built in regular expressions into the Perl script.

It might be reasonable to request that the Git folks enhance the userdiff code to be able to, as a plumbing command or via `git config --get`, expose the built in regular expressions.  Of course, you should also be aware that these regular expressions are approximations for what real parsers do, in general.  (C-like languages are particularly problematic because of macro substitutions—you have to run the entire input through a proper preprocessor before you can really find tokens.)

Note that the installed version of the Perl script is called `git-add--interactive` and lives in the "git-core" directory printed out by `git --exec-path`.  Since it *is* a script, it's pretty easy to modify.  It would probably be wisest, though, to copy that script to a new name in your own scripts directory, e.g., named `git-my-fancier-script`, and then invoke it as `git my-fancier-script`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.