# visually show diff output in a java program

Tags: java, diff, visual-diff

I am currently developing a java program where I need to show the difference between two text. 
Is there any library available for **visually** show the difference, that is the diff output in my java program or how can I do so. Any suggestion will be very helpful for me.

Comment: check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319479/generate-formatted-diff-output-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I would go for netbeans diff api.

- [How to use the diff api in netbeans](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/netbeans/how-to-use-the-diff-api-in-netbeans.html) and,
- [NetBeans Diff API](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_diff_api)

From the later url:

[image]

Although not a visual implementation, you also have [a translation of gnu diff in java](http://www.bmsi.com/java/#diff).

Comment: Thx for the solution. Can I able to use the netBeans Diff API in a standAlone Java Application?

Comment: Sure. It should be possible. You just need to get hold of the jar file containing the proper classes. Here is the api-documentation: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-diff/index.html?overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

JMeld is a library 
http://keeskuip.home.xs4all.nl/jmeld/
we have used successfully in our smartGENERATOR product.

The latest version 2.1 is available via
* http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeld/

JMeld 2.1 is available on the central maven repository 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jmeld|jmeld|2.1|jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmeld</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeld</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```