# File Compare and Highlight - Java

Tags: java, diff

I want to compare two text files and want to highlight the differences. Can any one of you help me in doing that thro Java program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are java diff classes scatered all around the internet. i'm sure you could find one by simply typing "java file diff"

Answer (score 1):

Copying one of my answers from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887115/visually-show-diff-output-in-a-java-program/2887117):

---

I would go for netbeans diff api.

- [How to use the diff api in netbeans](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/netbeans/how-to-use-the-diff-api-in-netbeans.html) and,
- [NetBeans Diff API](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_diff_api)

From the later url:

[image]

Although not a visual implementation, you also have [a translation of gnu diff in java](http://www.bmsi.com/java/#diff).

Answer (score 1):

The [google-diff-match-path](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library seems to provide the functionality you need. Here's a [demo](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html) of it in action.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse right click on filename in navigator bar, then select "Compare With".

Comment: Heh, this is a good answer. How to compare two files using a java program! :-)