# Diff files and mark as yellow in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, diff

Does anyone could recommend a framework or a java api that could help me compare two files? I would to compare both and mark one as yellow where we have the differences, like Tortoise do as example.

Comment: Using *Eclipse*: select two file -> right click -> *Compare with* -> *Each other*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573480/file-compare-and-highlight-java) seem to be related to what you are asking. There referred APIs and libraries include

[NetBeans Diff API](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_diff_api)

[google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)