# library for doing diffs

Tags: c++, diff

I've been tasked with creating a tool that can diff and merge the configuration files for my company's product.  The configurations are stored as either XML or URL-encoded strings.  I'm looking for a library, preferably open source with a license compatible with commercial software, that can do these diffs.  Our app is written in C++, so C++ libraries would be best, but I'm willing to look at libraries that are C#-specific since I can write a wrapper that exposes it to C++ via COM.  Three-way diffs would be ideal, but two-way is acceptable.  If it has an understanding of XML, that would also be a plus (since XML nodes can be reordered without changing the document, etc).  Any library suggestions?  Should I even consider writing my own diff tools in the hopes of giving it semantic knowledge of our formats?

Thanks to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479654/java-library-for-free-text-diff), I've already discovered [this google library](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), which seems really great, but I'm still looking for other options.  It also seems to be able to output the diffs in HTML format (using the `<ins>` and `<del>` tags that I didn't know existed before I discovered it), which could be really handy, but it seems to be a unified diff only.  I'm going to need to display the results in a web browser, and probably have to build an interface for doing the merges in the browser as well.  I don't expect a library to be able to help with these tasks, but it must produce output in a format that is amenable to me building this on top of it.  I'm currently envisioning something along the lines of TortoiseMerge (side-by-side diffs, not unified), except browser-based.  Any tips/tricks/design ideas on how to present this would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diffing the XML I would propose that you normalize it first: sort all the elements in alphabetic order, then generate a stream of tokens/xml that represents the original document but is independent of the original formatting. After running the diff, parse the result to get a tree containing what was added / removed.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion comes with `libsvn_diff` and `libsvn_delta` licensed under Apache Software License.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://ssddiff.alioth.debian.org/) is a C++ library that can diff what the author calls semistructured data. It deals nicely with HTML and XML.  Since your data is XML it would make a lot of sense to use this instead of plain text diff. This is especially the case when the files are machine generated.

I am currently trying to use this library to build a tool that diffs Visual Studio project files. These are basically XML files and using a plain diff tool like Winmerge is too painful because Visual Studio pretty much mucks up the whole file by crazy reordering. The idea is to do some kind of a structured diff to address the problem.