# Java simple String diff util

Tags: java, algorithm, string, swing, diff

I'm looking for a simple java lib/src to highlight differences between two Strings, case-sensitive. A html output would be great, but I would be happy to get the indexes of the diffs, something like:

```
diff("abcd","aacd") 
> [2,2]
diff("maniac", "brainiac")
> ["man",brain"] or [0,3] or something like that
```

The idea is to higlight typos or such in a swing program, since the input shold follow strict conventions.

Comment: identifying typos is a very complex problem. are you going to compare every input word with every valid word? please look up spelling suggestions etc on the web

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate, since you're asking for how to highlight the difference, but there are some good answers on [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java).

Comment: I'm not looking for input validation. I'm looking for string comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache Commons Lang has a class called StringUtils which has both difference and indexOfDifference which fulfills your needs.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Check it out

Answer (score 1):

The [java-diff](https://java-diff.dev.java.net/) project might also be useful.

> This is an implementation of the longest common subsequences (LCS) algorithm for Java. The `Diff#diff()` method returns a list of `Difference` objects, each of which describes an addition, a deletion, or a change between the two collections.