# How to Check for Newly-Inserted Words Between 2 Sentences in Java

Tags: java, compare

Anybody knows how to implement this scenario in Java?

> **sentence A** - This is a very simple sentence.
>
> **sentence B** - This is actually a simple sentence that I just made.
>
> **Output** - This is [actually] a simple sentence [that I just made.]

where the ones inside the brackets are the newly-added words.

Note: Im kinda new at this so I dont really know where to start :(

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good question to look at. You are esentially looking for String diffs
[How to perform string Diffs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java)