# Line diff with context in Java

Tags: java, diff

Is there a Java lib for line-based diff between multi-line text chunks, that supports before/after context lines, similarly to `diff -C` in the Unix toolkit?

For example, suppose the first chunk is

```
a
b
foo
c
d
```

and the second chunk is

```
a
b
goo
c
d
```

then diffing with one line of context should produce something like:

```
 b
-foo
+goo
 c
```

Preferably, this should be done using a native Java lib, not calling diff as an external process.

Comment: Have you evaluated http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/?

Comment: Check out this previous post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java

Comment: java-diff-utils is *really* under-documented. Can you list a short example? I didn't even find API docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't have anything to perform diff out of the box. But you can use [this](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) java library. This doesn't require you to call a process like `diff`

Comment: Comments already direct to diff-utils, but it's really undocumented. Could you please show an example?

Comment: They have a wiki with Example code. http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage

Comment: Examples are still very bad, but from reading the source code I somehow managed to get the general idea.