# Calculating string differences to build one string out of another using diff result

Tags: java, string

I need some library support to calculate difference between `string1` & `string2`. And use the difference result later to calculate `string2` using `string1` & diff result.

Actually, I need to implement something like post edits history like here at StackOverflow. I want to keep in DB the recent copy of post & difference w.r.t to old post. And use both of them whenever I need to see the old copy of post.

Have you heard of  any libraries that can help me out to calculate string difference ?

Comment: This question seems to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java

Comment: This question has been answered before in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Levenshtein distances to calculate differences between strings.

[Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

[Example in Javascript](https://github.com/CsRenan/Programming-Doodles/blob/master/levenshtein.js) (which you can adapt to Java fairly easily - there are examples in other languages in the wiki above too).

Comment: I'm not sure if a javascript implementation is relevant in a Java question.

Comment: @ChrisCooney Similar languages (in syntax), and you'd take just a few seconds to port the code from one into the other.

Comment: -1 but how do you reconstruct the other string from the string and the diff? levenstein is a one-way calculation

Comment: Then change the algorithm to return the difference matrix, not just the result. You can infer the indexes of the changes from there.

Comment: Then it's no longer Levenstein. It's something else. At a fundamental level, Levenstein is useless, because it's a lossy compression of the difference - like a hash. It is strictly one-way. Reconstituting one string from the other is not possible using any incantation of Levenstein.