# Trackchanges in xml file

Tags: java, xml

I'm interesting is there any library in Java to track changes in xml file.
For example we have xml file

```
 <Package name="Pack3">
    <Process name="Process1"/>
    <Type name="Type1"/>
    <Type name="Type2"/>
  </Package>
```

then we delete/add tag (I.E. )
So we have this code.

```
<Package name="Pack3">
    <Process name="Process1"/>
    <Type name="Type2"/>
  </Package>
```

So i want to track this changes , like in mercurial/github/etc.

It's not hard to do own parser , but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XML is just a string, you can use some diff analogs like Apache commons difference (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils) or [java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/).
Find more on string diff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java)