# Compare two Documents in a Service

Tags: android, html, service, compare, jsoup

I have a service where I "hit" my site every X Minutes and I want compare the "old" jsoup document to the new one to see if there is a change.

Any thoughts / help ?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.

    while(true)
    {

            new DoBackgroundTask().execute();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}

private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String response;
        response = "It Run!";
        try {
                Document results = Jsoup.connect("my site").get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DoBackgroundTask().execute();

            }
        }, 100000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your problem is?  Are you not able to connect to the site?  Not able to compare the results?  Looking for a better way of doing so?  Something else entirely?

Comment: Hey, sorry about the misunderstanding. I am trying to find a way to compare the 2 documents (the old one and the new one)

Answer (score 0):

When you hit your site, let Jsoup parse your HTML code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my-site").get();
```

Then store the results as a `String` with the current date.

```
saveNewVersion(new Date(), doc.outerHtml());
```

Now, find the latest version and compare it with the current version (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/132550/363573):

```
String oldDoc = loadLastestVersion();

// Find differences with google-diff-match-patch or java-diff-utils...
```

References:

- [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)
- [java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/)