# Is there any software to check minor difference in the our output and expected output

Tags: java

For instance you have provided an extra space . Such things are difficult to notice . 
I dont find any difference in the following two outputs but it still gives wrong answer as the answer

**My Output**

```
-150 can be fitted in:
* short
* int 
* long
150000 can be fitted in:
* int 
* long
1500000000 can be fitted in:
* int 
* long
213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:
* long
```

**Expected output**

```
-150 can be fitted in:
* short
* int
* long
150000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
1500000000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:
* long
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output to a text file and use [diff](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) to compare it to what you expect.

Comment: the command to use diff is  'diff inputFile outputFile'. You may direct your output to a file. Linux provides this utility in it OS kit.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Java libraries for this particular purpose. I would recommend [diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). Also see the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java) SO question for more recommendations.