# Json file comparision and finding the difference

Tags: java, json

I have two json files and I want to find the difference of those files.

for eg :
`file1` contains below contents.

```
"iClasses": [{
                                "name": "C1",
                                "label": "Classifier",
                                "description": "Blueprint of all classifications in LDM",
                                "isFirstClass": true,
                                "boost": "LOW",
                                "superClasses": []
                },
//same as above it contains 5 classes like c2,c3,c4 and c5 and has their own properties like label,classifier,boost etc.
]
```

`File2` contains only two classes which are present in file1 (let's say `C1` and `C2`).

If I compare these two files, it should show mismatch classes (say `C3`,`C4` and `C5` and it's contents) as difference.

Is there any way to find the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform string Diffs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a line by line comparison on text files you can use `diff` command which should available on most, if not all, unix like systems. If you are using Windows you can install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

You can use it on command line like:

```
diff file1 file2
```

For more options take a look at the output of following command

```
man diff
```

After that google is your friend.