# Can anyone help me to get extra character by comparing 2 inputed strings by using java

Tags: java, string, character

.For example if i enter two strings ,say input1="sum" and input 2="su". I should get an output saying 'm' is the extra character present in a string.

```
public class odd {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  boolean b = false;
  ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
  String n1="sum";
  String n2="su";
  for(int i=1;i<n1.length();i++){
    for(int j=1;j<n2.length();j++){
        if(n1.charAt(i)==n2.charAt(j)){
             b=true;
            break;
        } 
        else{
            System.out.println("Extra character is "+n1.charAt(i));
        }
  }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform string Diffs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132478/how-to-perform-string-diffs-in-java)

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing your homework with us. What have you tried so far? Have you made any effort whatsoever?

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far, what doesnt work? How is your thought process as to solving this problem?

Comment: @AlexKarlsson please check out the above code..it works partially.

Comment: @tnw please check the above code.

Comment: What's the actual problem? That's nice you have some code but you haven't told us what's wrong with it. Doesn't compile? If so, what's the compile error? Or does it compile but you encounter an exception? What's the exception? Maybe the output is wrong? BE MORE SPECIFIC AND DETAILED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way you can do it if the only condition is to find the extra character added, is to use split. So in your case it would look something like this:

```
String string1 = "sum";
String string2 = "su";
String[] array1 = string1.split(string2);
System.out.println(array1[1]);
```

This will print 'm'. And then you have to add conditions if you want to check which is the longer string etc. But this is a start.

Comment: And what if string1 is `sumsum` ? You'll get `m` with you code.

Comment: I did say this was a start of a solution, not a complete one, but its a pointer in the direction you can solve this with split. I dont think providing a full solution is helpful, since this is clearly a school assignment.

Comment: @Alex Karlsson I think i can use the above code as the base and apply some conditons to get proper output.

Comment: Ok, your solution is only valid for one character (as asked). I removed the `s`