# Text comparison algorithm or program?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am having Two paragraphs which are having sentences, I wanted to compare both the paragraphs and want to show the differences at UI.

Below are the possible use-cases, Which I can think about. Any help in algorithm or code will be appreciable.

[image]

Case 1: Word Deleted from str2

```
String str1 = "Hello I am new How are you";
String str2 = "How are you Hello";

output :
str1 = "<del>Hello I am new</del> How are you";
str2 = "How are you <add>Hello</add>"
```

Case 2:  Word added to str2

```
String str1 = "Hello How are you what about you";
String str2 = "How are you I am fine what about you";

output :
str1 = "<del>Hello</del> How are you what about you";
str2 = "How are you <add>I am fine</add> what about you"
```

Case 3: Words are equal

```
    String str1 = "Hello How are you";
    String str2 = "Hello How rea you";

    output :
    str1 = "Hello How <missmatch>are</missmatch> you";
    str2 = "Hello How <missmatch>rea</missmatch> you"
```

Comment: Shouldn't in the both cases 1 and 2 contain the 2nd string <del> instead of <add>? If you add the string `Hello` to `str2`, they won't be equal.

Comment: I'm not sure but there is an algorithm for spelling correction with delete insert etc called **Symmetric Delete Spelling Correction**. see http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/07/improved-edit-distance-based-spelling-correction/ you might get some idea

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis In Cases 1 and 2, substring has been added newly which is not matched in Str1

Comment: someone gave this question down vote, I don't know why?

Comment: Downvotes without any comment are bad practice !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. look at: https://github.com/wumpz/java-diff-utils and to its examples https://github.com/wumpz/java-diff-utils/wiki/Examples. The modification to include your specific tags instead of markup charactars is easy: e.g.

```
DiffRowGenerator generator = DiffRowGenerator.create()
                .showInlineDiffs(true)
                .mergeOriginalRevised(true)
                .inlineDiffByWord(true)
                .newTag(f -> f?"<span style=\"background-color:#ffc6c6\">":"</span>")
                .oldTag(f -> f?"<span style=\"background-color:#c4ffc3\">":"</span>")
                .columnWidth(10000000)
                .build();

List<DiffRow> rows = generator.generateDiffRows(
                Arrays.asList(lines.get(0)),
                Arrays.asList(lines.get(1)));

System.out.println(rows.get(0).getOldLine());
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the JAR and its Version for Diff-utils because I am getting compile error 'The method create() is undefined for the type DiffRowGenerator.'

Comment: I got it from your first link, Thanks Let me try your approach.

Comment: You have to compile it yourself. Other versions of former googles java-diff-utils are at maven central (I think version 1.3.0). But This code snipped works for version 2.0-SNAPSHOT at the repository at github. Beware the changed groupid.

Comment: getting error : "Missing artifact com.github.java-diff-utils:diffutils:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT" at POM.xml

Comment: [WARNING] The POM for com.github.java-diff-utils:diffutils:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: No, i did not :( I am just adding dependency at POM.xml and trying to Install, getting BUILD FAILURE. Do I need to add any other extra JAR's, I am new to Maven

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.java-diff-utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>diffutils</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Aha. I see. As I said. You have to checkout java-diff-utils from the repository and make there a "clean install". Then you have the needed JAR in your local repository and now you should be able to build your project.

Comment: Yes. With 2.0-SNAPSHOT v8 is needed. You could downgrade to another version. But as ever there is less functionality.

Comment: You should definitly give Java v8 a try.

Comment: Yeah I did it and got the Jar's 1) 'diffutils-2.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar' 2) diffutils-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, Let me try further steps. I will update you for sure :)

Comment: Working Like Champ :) Marvelous, Let me use this in my real use case. Thanks, Good Job

Comment: How can I use your JAR's in Java v7, Is there any other way? Because my current project is in Java 7.

Comment: I refactored it heavily to Java 8. So very problematic for v 2.

Comment: can I use these Jars in my project, Its freeware Right?

Comment: Part of it is licensed under Apache V2 and the histogram diff part is Eclipse licensed. These are open source licenses which allow usage under specific conditions in even commercial projects. The term freeware is imho wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149721/discussion-between-user3676578-and-wumpz).